# Formula for Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I need to do a plan for my team.
Name, time of working, and I need a formula that can assign randomly in the slot of 1 hour: chat, call break, and task.

It is a team of 15 people, I can't find any formula for this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add more descriptive information about your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all possible entries in a column (say `A`) and use a combination of `INDEX` and `RANDBETWEEN` to select a random entry:

```
=INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(1,3),1)
```

Here `1` and `3` are the first and last row of the entry list.

[image]

Note that whenever you change a cell, `RANDBETWEEN` will generate a new number, which leads to a potential change to *all* cells. You need to [paste values](https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/how-to-copy-and-paste-values-only-in-google-sheets/) to make them permanent.

Comment: thank you, nice this formula you advised me, now it is possible to add a rule, so that an agent per day has 1 break, 2 chats and 2 calls, and the rest task so that in a group of 15 people for the same time there is coverage with 2 chats and 2 calls, I don't know if I made myself clear, I also attached the screen with the color reference.

Comment: That makes it a lot more complicated, I'll have a look but I don't want this to turn into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/295232).

Comment: omg, I hope not, anyway thanks for the help!